# Interesting program behaviour

Tags: c++

So I have a little program

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void lol() {
    cout << "How did we get here?"<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   long a, b, z[10];
   cin >> a >> b;
   z[a] = b;
}
```

You can run it via online compiler [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp11_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMVDdBTVo4WjIyRTQ)

The program has no purpose, but it has one bug or feature - I do not know what it is. 
So, if you write something like this
`main 13 2015` you'll probably get nothing, but if you enter two magic number `13` and `4196608` you'll get an error. Moreover the program executes function `void lol()` and prints the line `How did we get here?`.

I've run `nm ./main` and found my function `void lol()` with the address `0000000000400900` which equals `4196608`(base of the system of numeration is 10).

That means that the program "jumps" for some reason to this address and executes the function `void lol()`. Moreover, if I change the first number, nothing will happen. 
`main 10 4196608`, `main 11 4196608`, `main 12 4196608`, `main 14 4196608`, `main 15 4196608` -- all the same, no errors, but as soon as I enter number `13` I get this interesting behaviour.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: wow. you discovered undefined behaviour. Well, it's best you learn early. But rest assured, it's not "interesting". It's a pain you'll be avoiding for all the time spent programming

Comment: Could you give me some more information on which system you are running your test? I could not replicate your behavior in my machine.

Comment: You have discovered one way how buffer overflows cause security flaws.

Comment: I would try it, but I'm not sure if Raid works on nasal demons.

Answer (score 7):

If the input for `a` is a number above 9 (or negative), you are accessing `z[a]` incorrectly (out of bound index, [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)) since you declared an array `long z[10]`

This is typical **[undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** (UB).

UB is **very bad**, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of mine, or for more background:

- [Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior?s=4|2.8667)
- [What are all the common undefined behaviours that a C++ programmer should know about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a?s=3|3.3064)

The only way to explain some actual undefined behavior is to dive into all the implementation specific details (compiler, optimization, operating system, machine code, processor, etc....). You could spend years on this. (perhaps in your case the return address on the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) has been overwritten by the address of `lol` function).

Comment: I understand that it is an undefined behavior, but why it happens when I enter number 13? Not 11, 10 or 15, but 13?

Comment: @Ascelhem if you understand assembly, you can study the output of your compiler and maybe figure it out.

Comment: My guess is that you are messing with the stack unwinding code used by the exception system.

Comment: I didnt know that the `ret` instruction takes the address from the stack, so @basile-starynkevitch guess is more accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Using the information that Basile Starynkevitch gave us, I made some experimentation whose results strongly suggests that you are messing with the return address.

I created an intermediate function `main2()` which will return to `main()`, so we know what we expect in the stack position regarding the [return address](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_280.html) of the function. My code prints the previous value in `z[a]` and I compare it with the memory position of the caller, i.e. the `main()` function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void lol() {
    cout << "How did we get here?"<<std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv);

void main2()
{
   long a, b, z[10];
   b = reinterpret_cast<long>(&lol);
   a = 15; //The offset depends on your machine, I found out 15 by trial and error
   std::cout << "z[a] was " << z[a] << std::endl;
   std::cout << "main() was " << reinterpret_cast<long>(&main) << std::endl;
   z[a] = b;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    main2();
}
```

The output is:

```
z[a] was 4196677
main() was 4196657
How did we get here?
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I dont know the size of each instruction once compiled to x86 64bits, but the th instruction of `main` implementation in the asssembly, is the `call` instruction:

```
main:
.LFB1022:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    %edi, -4(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    call    _Z5main2v
```

which could explain the offset of 20 bytes in `main` address and what we had originally in `z[a]`.